# What options do you have in Rails in creating a Restful API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I want people to be able to perform operations in ruby scripts using an API.

What options do you have in rails?

What if I want certain operations to be authenticated?

Answer (score 2):

You can make any resource RESTful in rails by using `resources` in the routes.rb file. So if you have a table called items, then you could go `resources :items`. This will automagically make your controller accept any of the seven standard RESTful actions, new, create, index, etc.

Rails can deal with lots of different formats out of the box, html, json, xml, etc. So if you want someone to search your items, the code would look something like this when you go to a url that looks something like mydomain.com/items.json?search_term=HelloWorld:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @item = Item.find_by_name(params[:search_term])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @item}
      format.json { render :json => @item }   # this will get returned
    end

  end
end
```

If you want operations to be authenticated, then you could use something like the omniauth gem to do OAuth authentication via facebook, or something like that. You'll need some sort of library on your client side to manage the session as well, unless you recommend doing something icky like passing your user/pass in the URL.